# View controller animating in subviews on init when using auto layout?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a programmatically made view controller with subviews that are positioned using constraints. When I push this view controller into view using a navigation controller with the animation disabled...

```
let viewController = InventoryViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```

...the view controller does not simply appear on screen, its subviews (the ones with constraints) expand outward and into view. Subviews that are not given constraints simply appear on screen as expected. So obviously, auto layout is animating itself into view. How do I disable this animation and just have the subviews appear on screen?

```
class InventoryViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {

        view = UIView()
        view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        addButton()

    }

    func addButton() {

        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 36).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true          

    }

    @objc func buttonAction() {

       //  

    }

}
```

Comment: your question is quite unclear can you elaborate more, what do you want it to animate? or you don't want? do you want those subviews to appear on the same view instead of pushing the view?

Comment: What is unclear? Subviews of the view controller with constraints animate into view (by stretching out from zero) and subviews without constraints simply appear on screen without animating into view. How do I disable this default constraint animation?

Comment: try setting frame for your button before applying constraint. for example like " let button = UIButton() ; button.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 36, width: view.bounds.width - 32, height: 48)"

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.. I am not seeing anything animate.

Comment: @swanstation you should provide a small Xcode project to be downloaded, that reprocudes the issue.

Comment: Did you override the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? If yes how? Is there any `UIView.beginAnimations(, context:)` or is your push in an animation block?

Comment: You should be configuring your view in `viewDidLoad()`, not `loadView()`.
Is there a particular reason you're doing it that way?

Comment: I created a playground here : https://gist.github.com/PierreMardon/29fe5d14de87fbb095f7850d8cda271b

It exactly executes what you describe without reproducing your problem. Can you provide some more details ? I guess pushing your view controller happens in some other UI presentation / navigation flow..?

Answer (score 5):

Pushing the view controller is what causes its view to be loaded. You could try to force this to load and layout before the push:

```
let viewController = InventoryViewController()
viewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```

Comment: You could omit the `loadViewIfNeeded` because `view` calls `loadView` for you automatically.

Answer (score 3):

`loadView()` is not a good place to configure your subviews, it should be used only to put the views in your view hierarchy, probably that is why you view is animating.

Try to set your subviews on `viewDidLoad()` method.

Please look the discussion section in the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

Answer (score 1):

Call your method from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` after `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews`. And animation will not be seen. As the reason behind this is using Autolayout, frame of your views are set when the autolayout engine starts its calculation.
This method is called when the autolayout engine has finished to calculate your views' frames

Answer (score 1):

use
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

Answer (score -1):

You use layoutIfNeeded() on the view they are added to, to force layout/redraw immediately.

Do this in viewDidLoad or try right after you have set the constraints.

or try:

```
layoutSubviews()
setNeedsLayout()
layoutSubviews()
```

Comment: Directly calling `layoutSubviews()` is bad practice,  You should always `setNeedsLayout()`, then `layoutIfNeeded()`.